# Matplotlib.pyplot.ginput() in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, ginput

I am using Jupyter Notebook while running the below code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.sin(a)
plt.plot(a,b)
print("After 3 clicks:")
x = plt.ginput(3)
print(x)
plt.show()
```

While running this code I get the below warning

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
x = plt.ginput(3)
```

Due to this issue, I am not able to click the points on graph nor I am getting the clicked points in output.

The python in my system is of version is 3.9.7 and matplotlib is of version 3.4.3.

Comment: What does `plt.get_backend()` return?

Comment: It returns `'module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline'` in system.

Comment: Thank you @OluwafemiSule because examining for `plt.get_backend()` command led me to the useful command `matplotlib.use()` which helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I used matplotlib.use() before importing pyplot.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.sin(a)
plt.plot(a,b)
print("After 3 clicks:")
x = plt.ginput(3)
print(x)
plt.show()
```

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg') this changed the non -gui backend to GUI backend of Qt5Agg.